# How is an object which does not subclass BindingProvider be casted explicitly into a BindingProvider object?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, soap-client

I have a web service where I'm manipulating the SOAP headers using the service interface object in the client API.

I needed to type cast the port object into a `BindingProvider` object. But my port object does not directly subclass that class. So how is it possible that the JVM doesn't complain?

And it works too. No runtime error of ClassCastException

Code snippet:

```
    public SearchDocument getSearchDocumentService(String wsdlUri, AuthBean auth){
    SearchDocument_Service serv = null;
    serv = SearchDocument_Service.getServiceInstance(wsdlUri);
    SearchDocument searchDoc = serv.getSearchDocument();

    populateAuthAndHandlerInfo((BindingProvider)searchDoc, auth);//how is it that jvm doesn't complain here
    return searchDoc;
    }

    private void populateAuthAndHandlerInfo(BindingProvider port, AuthBean auth) {
    Binding binding = port.getBinding();
              List<Handler> handlerList = binding.getHandlerChain();
              handlerList.add(new EDMSSoapAuthHandler());
              binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);
        Map<String, Object> context = port.getRequestContext();
        context.put("clientAuthInfo", auth);
        }
```

SearchDocument.java:

```
    @WebService(name = "SearchDocument", targetNamespace = "http://services.abc.com/Technology/SearchDocument/service/v1")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface SearchDocument {


    /**
     * 
     * @param body
     * @return
     *     returns com.abc.technology.search.document.client.v1.SearchOnMetadataResponse
     * @throws AbcServiceException
     * @throws AbcInvalidMessageException
     * @throws AbcProducerApplicationException
     */
    @WebMethod(action = "http://services.abc.com/Technology/SearchDocument/service/v1/soap11/SearchDocument/searchOnMetadata")
    @WebResult(name = "SearchOnMetadataResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.abc.com/Technology/SearchDocument/contract/v1", partName = "body")
    public SearchOnMetadataResponse searchOnMetadata(
        @WebParam(name = "SearchOnMetadata", targetNamespace = "http://services.abc.com/Technology/SearchDocument/contract/v1", partName = "body")
        SearchOnMetadataRequest body)
        throws AbcInvalidMessageException, AbcProducerApplicationException, AbcServiceException
    ;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to answer your question.

## From a high level perspective

> But my port object does not directly subclass that class. So how is it possible the JVM doesn't complain ?

Well... `SearchDocument` is an interface. So, when you call

```
SearchDocument searchDoc = serv.getSearchDocument();
```

Then `searchDoc` is an instance of a given type that implements the interface, but it is nowhere specified what this concrete class is. It could be anything, including a concrete class that implements both `SearchDocument` and `BindingProvider`, because both are interfaces and any given type is free to implement multiple interfaces at the same time.
So this kind of *must be* what is happening here, right ?

## From the JAX WS specification

Looking at the JAXWS spec may enlighten you further. you can download it at https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224, but I'll quote a few nuggets for you, at chapter 4.2.3 :

> Proxies provide access to service endpoint interfaces at runtime without requiring static generation of a stubclass.  See java.lang.reflect.Proxy
>   for more information on dynamic proxies as supported by the JDK
>
> ...
>
> Conformance (Implementing BindingProvider): **An instance of a proxy MUST implement javax-.xml.ws.BindingProvider**
>
> ...
>
> **A proxy is created using the getPort methods** of a Service instance: T getPort(Class sei) Returns a proxy for the specified SEI

Now it's easy to bring the pieces back together.

### What is a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` thing.

In the JVM, there is an API for creating proxy objects. `Proxy` objects (instances) are a special kind of beast in the JVM, that can be created dynamically, at runtime, and each proxy can be made to conform to any given interface. It's like creating a `Class` at runtime, not at compile time, and without having to write its java source file. Of course, there are all kind of limitations, but also many possibilities.

One is to say to the JVM : "hey, give me a `Proxy` object that implements the interfaces `SearchDocument`and `BindingProvider` at the same time". And so does the JVM. It gives you back an object, whose concrete class is `Proxy` (usually Proxy$x where x is a number), and is specially crafted to implement both interface.

If you wonder if this is of any use at this point, then no it is not, because creating a type that has no implementation is kind of pointless. But there's a way to provide an implentation and behaviour, through what is called an `InvocationHandler` that you program (exactly how is another discussion).

So, at this point, what we get from the specification is that if we call `getPort` on a `javax.xml.ws.Service` then, the result MUST be a JDK proxy, that MUST also implement `BindingProvider`.

### Back to your case

Which, I bet, is exactly what happens when you call : `SearchDocument_Service`, it ultimately calls a `getPort` method, and makes sure that the result implements `BindingProvider`, because JAXWS says it must do so, and your `SearchDocument` "business" interface, because it is what is usefull to you.

Comment: Nailed it!! And as you said, there is a getPort() method called in the `SearchDocument_Service` impl class. I totally get it now. Though all this is just a little complicated to process as a whole(proxy> network> service endpoint > etc etc.. and back!). Thanks GPI :) I will give this is +1 as soon as I get a rep of 15

Comment: Not an issue, I don't mind my rep so so so much. Maybe you can still accept the answer, though.

It is complicated, but it's so clever to be able to mask implementation between an interface (if you think a litlle about it, a WSDL PortType IS an interface, so the way JAXWS proxies an interface to put the Serialisation/XML and Network logic is, in my view, pretty clever!).